# AWS EC2 replace ipv4 with domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a EC2 instance on ipv4 address 123.4.5.6:8080 for example, in the future if I have a domain name, how do I switch to this domain name? do I need to change port 8080 to port 80? If not how do I keep port 8080 with a domain name? thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tomcat not running on port 80 on aws ec2 instance of ubuntu 16.04LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43575300/tomcat-not-running-on-port-80-on-aws-ec2-instance-of-ubuntu-16-04lts)

Answer (score 1):

A DNS record is just something like a translation table between the domain name and the IP address.

- Your server keeps the IP address.
- At the provider, where you buy the domain name, create an [A Record](https://www.godaddy.com/garage/dns-records-a-beginners-guide/) mapping the domain name to the IP address.

If you want to keep the port, you can, nothing prevents you to do so (you will need to explicitly provide the port number the same way you do with the IP address)

Comment: Thank you! I found a solution to redirect all traffics from port 80 to port 8080. This way I don't need add that port 8080 after every url. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43575300/tomcat-not-running-on-port-80-on-aws-ec2-instance-of-ubuntu-16-04lts